# Spring Boot redirect all URL to index.html (SPA)

Tags: regex, angular, spring-boot, single-page-application

Im trying to create a default **RequestMapping** which redirects all requests to **index.html** in my single page application

my current solution is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

and in the properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

im building an social network and it works if i create paths like

http://localhost:8080/user1337

but when i use dots in my path it fails:

http://localhost:8080/user.1337

i get an error page:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 18 23:19:22 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: Maybe you want to match any paths? `{[path:.*}`?

Comment: when i match any paths i get an exception...  ServletException: Circular view path [/index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="{path:.*}")
```

This pattern

```
[^\\.]
```

Matches any character which is not `\` or `\` or `.`, so it would follow that your pattern would not match a path with a `.` in it, and thus would not redirect to index.